# How do I disable caching for the Forum module or, alternatively, how do I fix caching?

Tags: 8, caching

I use the normal standard Drupal Forum module with a clean Drupal 8 installation. After I have installed it, I have a problem where "2 new posts" shows for all users. In other words, the /forum page is caching and showing the cached page of one user for the other user.

So I have two options

1. Disable caching for /forum <--- I don't mind doing this for now, as there aren't many users at the moment so I have time to fix this properly later.
2. Figure out why this page is caching the way it is. As mentioned, I am using a clean installation with hardly any confirm and this still happens.

Can someone confirm if the /forum page normally does this or if something is probably wrong with my installation? Or maybe I'm missing some setting? Or maybe caching is meant to be disabled for this to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How to disable cache for particular page, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/151289/72672

Comment: The same thing happens to me. Most pages are cached and showing old things as new etc. I can't see how this page can work with caching enabled, so I'm also looking for answers?

Comment: Fixing the module would be off-topic here, this belongs in the issue queue. For the underlying question, how to vary the cache by the current user, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281230/wrong-user-image-display-weird-twig-cache

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on a fresh install?

Answer (score -2):

This documentation is the most suitable for your query: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Please learn all the details on that page and the other associated page. This may resolve your issue.

Thank you.